# R: Counting the Number of Iterations required to Optimize a Function

Tags: r, optimization

I am working with the R programming language.

I defined the following function:

```
f1 <- function(x) {

 

  i <<- i+1

  vals[[i]] <<- x

    final_value = x[1]^2 + x[2]^2

}
```

and then optimized this function:

```
i <- 0 
vals <- list()
res <- optim(c(1,1), f1, method="CG")
```

I am trying to understand the outputs of the "optim" (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optim) function:

```
$par
[1] -4.103643e-07 -4.103643e-07

$value
[1] 3.367978e-13

$counts
function gradient 
      26       11 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

In particular, I am trying to understand the "count" arguments. Reading the documentation, the following explanation is given:

*counts:
A two-element integer vector giving the number of calls to fn and gr respectively. This excludes those calls needed to compute the Hessian, if requested, and any calls to fn to compute a finite-difference approximation to the gradient.*

I would have thought that "counts" would refer to the number of iterations it took for the function to be optimized. But when I look at the number of iterations, the total number of iterations does not match the output of "counts":

```
> vals

[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 1.001 1.000

[[3]]
[1] 0.999 1.000

[[4]]
[1] 1.000 1.001

....

[[68]]
[1] -1.000410e-03 -4.103643e-07

[[69]]
[1] -4.103643e-07  9.995896e-04

[[70]]
[1] -4.103643e-07 -1.000410e-03
```

For instance, it appears that 70 iterations were used to optimize this function, but the "counts" argument suggests that 26 iterations were used.

**Can someone please help me understand what "counts" is referring to and what is the difference between 70 and 26 in this question?**

Thanks!

Comment: If each time the gradient is calculated the Hessian is also calculated and if it takes 4 function evaluations for both then 26 + 4 * 11 equals 70.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation states, the function `optims` does not count all function calls. If the function was called e.g. to compute the Hessian derivative, or an approximation steps, `vals` will get one more value, but `res$counts[["function"]]` won't thus this value is smaller (26) compared to the total number of function calls (70). The function you want to optimize is very simple, so there aren't many iterations needed and most calls (70-26) is just administration overhead. The higher the difference, the less fraction of the time you spent on the main part (the actual optimization).